# g++ __thread = non-trivial constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, g++

I'd like to use __thread modifier, as a substitution for thread_local from C++11, in g++. Unfortunately my local thread variable doesn't have trivial constructor (it has to set the value of one integer components).
I think about using this kind of construction:

```
__thread MyVariable *var;

__thread MyVariable* MyClass::var = nullptr;
```

End every time I'd like to get an acces to var I check if it was allocated:

```
if(var == nullptr)
   var = new MyVariable(42);
```

But I have no idea, how to free allocated in this way memory.

Comment: `delete` it at the end of your threads lifetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__thread` storage specifier can not handle objects with non-trivial constructors and destructors.

For objects with non-trivial constructors and destructors you may like to use `boost::thread_specfic_ptr<>`. When a thread terminates `boost::thread_specfic_ptr<>` invokes `delete` on the corresponding thread-specific object.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use boost::thread_specific_ptr<> inside a class, which will be passed to std::thread.

http://pastebin.com/vckyqLME

Comment: `boost::thread_specfic_ptr<>` is non-copyable, however, an instance of `Run` gets copied when passed to `thread` constructor.

Comment: Explain the problem you're trying to solve with thread-specific storage. Sample code you posted doesn't give enough context.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small demo program to show how to define a thread_local macro that works with non-trivial types and stores everything with __thread duration.  It is superior to boost::thread_specific_ptr because it doesn't do any dynamic memory allocation.

See my answer to this question:

[gcc 4.7 on linux pthreads - nontrivial thread_local workaround using __thread (no boost)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049684/gcc-4-7-on-linux-pthreads-nontrivial-thread-local-workaround-using-thread-n)