# C++11: Nontrivial Thread Local Static Variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-local, thread-local-storage

I have a class X:

```
class X { ... }
```

I want to do this:

```
void f()
{
    thread_local static X x = ...;

    ...
}
```

(actually I'm using gcc so keyword is "__thread")

but I can't because you can only have trivial thread_locals.

What is the best work-around for this?

If I do it this way:

```
void f()
{
    thread_local static X* p = 0;

    if (!p)
       p = new X(...);

    X& x = *p;

    ...
}
```

then:

1. the destructor won't be called when thread exits
2. unnecessary dynamic memory allocation.

**Update:**

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class X { public: X() { cout << "X::X()" << endl; }; ~X() { cout << "X::~X()" << endl; } };

void f()
{
        static __thread bool x_allocated = false;
        static __thread aligned_storage<sizeof(X),
             alignment_of<X>::value>::type x_storage;

        if (!x_allocated)
        {
                new (&x_storage) X;
                x_allocated = true;
                // add thread cleanup that calls destructor
        }

        X& x = *((X*) &x_storage);
}

int main()
{
        f();
}
```

This fixes the dynamic memory allocation problem.  I just need to add the thread cleanup handler.  Is there a mechanism to do this with pthreads?

Comment: Why you can have only trivial thread-locals? Par of standard?

Comment: I thought so?  GCC doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: @ForEveR I don't think the standard has such restrictions, and GCC does not implement C++11 thread local storage yet.

Comment: @juanchopanza: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html

Comment: That is a gcc extension, not C++11 `thread_local`. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). So whenever it is implemented, you will not have the triviality problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yeah I see now.  What is the best workaround in the meantime?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling sorry, if I knew I would have provided an answer :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049684/gcc-4-7-on-linux-pthreads-nontrivial-thread-local-workaround-using-thread-n

Comment: I think I'm having a case where thread_local non-POD object is not initialized in VS 2015 when using the native library from .NET. Sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Standard describes `thread_local` as a storage specifier like the others (`static`, `extern` etc.) in §7.1.1. There is no restriction to "simple" data types by any definition of that word.

The problem is briefly discussed in a [pre-C++11 discussion document N2147](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2147.html) (see the section "Thread Variable Dynamic Initialization"). That includes a description of the key problems involved in the proper implementation. Apparently the GCC implementation (`static __thread`) hasn't solved these problems yet (which is consistent with the fact that GCC does not officially support C++11 `thread_local`).

One alternative is `boost::thread_specfic_ptr<>` mentioned [in this earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149029/777186) and described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/doc/html/boost/thread_specific_ptr.html).

Another alternative is to use a `std::thread` object to implement the thread and ensure each instance maintains its own copy of the variable, possibly wrapped in a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I need to change my question slightly (maybe need to post new one).  Using boost or std::thread is not an option in my environment.  I have got the dynamic allocation problem fixed (see my update), however I still need a way to call the destructor on thread exit.  Is there a way to do this with pthreads?  (I realize this is now a gcc specific question)

Comment: I'll post new question, it's easier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049684/gcc-4-7-on-linux-pthreads-nontrivial-thread-local-workaround-using-thread-n

Answer (score 6):

`thread_local` and `__thread` are, in fact, not the same thing. The main difference between them is precisely the one you stumbled upon - `thread_local` allows the variable to be non-POD. Unfortunately, this also has performance implications. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106049/c11-gcc-4-8-thread-local-performance-penalty) for more details about those performance implications.