# gcc 4.7 on linux pthreads - nontrivial thread_local workaround using __thread (no boost)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

In C++11 you can have a non-trivial object with thread_local storage:

```
class X { ... }

void f()
{
    thread_local X x = ...;
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately this feature hasn't been implemented in gcc yet (as of 4.7).

gcc does allow you to have thread local variables but only with trivial types.

I am looking for a workaround:

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

class X
{
public:
    X() { cout << "X::X()" << endl; };
    ~X() { cout << "X::~X()" << endl; }
};

typedef aligned_storage<sizeof(X), alignment_of<X>::value>::type XStorage;

inline void placement_delete_x(X* p) { p->~X(); }

void f()
{
        static __thread bool x_allocated = false;
        static __thread XStorage x_storage;

        if (!x_allocated)
        {
                new (&x_storage) X;
                x_allocated = true;

                // TODO: add thread cleanup that
                //     calls placement_delete_x(&x_storage)
        }

        X& x = *((X*) &x_storage);
}

int main()
{
        f();
}
```

What I need help with is calling placement_delete_x(&x_storage) on exit of the current thread.  Is there a mechanism in pthreads and/or linux I can use to do this?  I would need to add a function pointer and a parameter to some sort of pthread cleanup stack?

**Update:**

I think `pthread_cleanup_push` might be what I want:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html

Will this call the cleanup handler in the correct circumstances for this usage?

**Update 2:**

It looks like `boost::thread_specific_ptr` eventually calls `pthread_key_create` with the `destructor` parameter, and not `pthread_cleanup_push` - to call its tls cleanup function:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/pthread_key_create.html

It is unclear what the difference between these two methods is, if any. ?

Comment: Maybe [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html) can help.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: See last two words of title. :) In any case, boost::thread_specifc_ptr requires a dynamic memory allocation - whereas in above solution storage is __thread allocated.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Actually I lied, you could use `explicit thread_specific_ptr(void (*cleanup_function)(T*));` in above solution to call placement_delete_x.  But alas, I can't use boost.  What mechanism does boost::thread_specific_ptr use to call the cleanup handler?  (I suppose I could eat the source and find out)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot your weird prohibition. I'll leave the comment here as it might be helpful to those who are able to use useful third-party libraries. I imagine that it would use `pthread_cleanup_push` on POSIX platforms, but you'd have to look at the source to be sure.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Not sure it's so weird, most boost libraries including boost threads are not allowed according to Google Coding Guidelines: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Boost for example.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: turns out it uses pthread_key_create.  see update 2.

Comment: Google bans the use of exceptions, and any library that might throw exceptions. That's arguably reasonable if you have to deal with a large legacy codebase written with the assumption that exceptions don't exist, but is very bad advice for productive C++ development. Unfortunately, many organisations seem to be blindly following their guidelines, just as in previous decades they would blindly follow Microsoft's guidelines, without considering whether they actually make sense. I like to think that such lunacy is the exception not the rule, but that's probably putting too much faith in humanity.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I don't think it is just about exceptions.  The reason I (and many companies) don't allow boost is that it is completely overengineered.  In so many cases I have a simple problem that requires a few lines of code, whereas somehow boost manages to turn it into a 4000 line monstrosity.  It's fine that that's hidden in implementation - UNTIL - there is a bug, then you have to open the black box to find all boosts wonderful moving parts.  See slide "Refuctoring #2: Treasure Hunt" in this presentation: http://waterfall2006.com/Refuctoring.pdf

Comment: You could explicitly call the destructor with `(&x)->~X()` which gives you "placement delete"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: You haven't understood the problem.  It needs to be called once at thread exit.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That's exactly what the `placement_delete_x` function does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mike says `pthread_cleanup_push` is not appropriate.  The correct way is to use `pthread_key_create`.

I've implemented a small demo program to show how to do it.  We implement a macro `thread_local` that you use like this:

With the real C++11 feature it would be:

```
void f()
{
    thread_local X x(1,2,3);
    ...
}
```

With this it is:

```
void f()
{
    thread_local (X, x, 1, 2, 3);
    ...
}
```

The difference between this and boost::thread_specifc_ptr is that there is zero dynamic memory allocation.  Everything is stored with `__thread` duration.  It is also significantly lighter-weight, but it is gcc/linux specific.

Overview:

1. We used `std::aligned_storage` to make __thread duration space for the variable
2. On first entry from a given thread we use placement new to construct the variable in the storage
3. We also `__thread` allocate a linked list entry to the placement delete call
4. We use `pthread_setspecific` to keep track of each threads list head
5. The function passed to `pthread_key_create` walks the list calling the placement deletes when the thread exits.

...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

static pthread_key_t key;
static pthread_once_t once_control = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

struct destructor_list
{
    void (*destructor)(void*);
    void* param;
    destructor_list* next;
};

static void execute_destructor_list(void* v)
{
    for (destructor_list* p = (destructor_list*) v; p != 0; p = p->next)
        p->destructor(p->param);
}

static void create_key()
{
    pthread_key_create(&key, execute_destructor_list);
}

void add_destructor(destructor_list* p)
{
    pthread_once(&once_control, create_key);

    p->next = (destructor_list*) pthread_getspecific(key);
    pthread_setspecific(key, p);
}

template<class T> static void placement_delete(void* t) { ((T*)t)->~T(); }

#define thread_local(T, t, ...)                         \
T& t = *((T*)                                           \
({                                                      \
    typedef typename aligned_storage<sizeof(T),         \
        alignment_of<T>::value>::type Storage;          \
    static __thread bool allocated = false;             \
    static __thread Storage storage;                    \
    static __thread destructor_list dlist;              \
                                                        \
    if (!allocated)                                     \
    {                                                   \
        new (&storage) T(__VA_ARGS__);                  \
        allocated = true;                               \
        dlist.destructor = placement_delete<T>;         \
        dlist.param = &storage;                         \
        add_destructor(&dlist);                         \
    }                                                   \
                                                        \
    &storage;                                           \
}));

class X
{
public:
    int i;

    X(int i_in) { i = i_in; cout << "X::X()" << endl; };

    void f() { cout << "X::f()" << endl; }

    ~X() { cout << "X::~X() i = " << i << endl; }
};

void g()
{
    thread_local(X, x, 1234);
    x.f();
}

int main()
{
    thread t(g);
    t.join();
}
```

Notes:

1. You need to add error checking to each pthread_* call.  I just removed it for exposition.
2. It uses `__thread` which is a GNU extension
3. It uses an *expression statement* to keep the auxillary __thread variable names out of the parent scope.  This is also a GNU extension.

Comment: I am pretty new to C++. Can you explain the why aligned storage is required in this case? Btw great work on working out a solution to this. This was just what I wanted.

Comment: @chamibuddhika: (1) aligned storage provides appropriately aligned uninitialized storage for an object of type T.  Otherwise the storage will be misaligned.  (2) This question and solution is now obsoleted by the real `thread_local` core language feature of C++11 and following.  See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: Have you published the full solution anywhere, e.g., github?

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_key_create` and friends are what you'd want to implement thread-specific variables of types with destructors. However, these generally require you to manage the whole process of creating and destroying the variables, and I'm not sure whether you could use them in conjunction with `__thread`.

`pthread_cleanup_push` is not suitable. It's intended to allow a resource to be released if the thread exits during a (short) block of code that uses that resource; as described in the documentation you link to, it *must* be matched by a `pthread_cleanup_pop` at the same level of that function, and the handler won't be called if the thread returns from its main function. That means that you can't use it if you want the thread-local variable to persist between calls to the function.

For the benefit of those who don't have a prohibition against third-party libraries, [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html) provides a convenient, portable way to manage thread-local storage.

Comment: Sorry, why can't you use `pthread_key_create` in conjunction with `__thread`?  The `destructor` function parameter of `pthread_key_create` is called on thread exit - so I think all I need to do is have it call `placement_delete_x` right?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure; I don't know enough about the details of `__thread` to know whether you could cobble together some kind of hybrid between that and `pthreads`. I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: I've got it working, it's pretty straight-forward.  `__thread` just stores the variable in a per-thread static area, rather than in the heap or in the global static area.  I'll post the code shortly.

Comment: I've added a demo, see my answer.