# What is the performance penalty of C++11 thread_local variables in GCC 4.8?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gcc, c++11

From the [GCC 4.8 draft changelog](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html#cxx):

> G++ now implements the [C++11](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html) `thread_local` keyword; this differs from
>   the GNU `__thread` keyword primarily in that it allows dynamic
>   initialization and destruction semantics. Unfortunately, this support
>   requires a run-time penalty for references to non-function-local
>   `thread_local` variables even if they don't need dynamic initialization,
>   so users may want to continue to use `__thread` for TLS variables with
>   static initialization semantics.

What is precisely the nature and origin of this run-time penalty?

Obviously to support non-function-local `thread_local` variables there needs to be a thread initialization phase before the entry to every thread main (just as there is a static initialization phase for global variables), but are they referring to some run-time penalty beyond that?

Roughly speaking what is the architecture of gcc's new implementation of thread_local?

Comment: I really think the GCC mailing list would be a better place to ask (and most likely get an answer, although [Jonathan Wakely](http://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) and other GCC/libstdc++ devs are lurking here and may know more). Interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: There's some relevant discussion in the thread starting with http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-10/msg00024.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I don't know much about the internals of GCC, so this is also an educated guess.)

The dynamic `thread_local` initialization is added in commit [462819c](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=462819c8e20aab1124e95392974dd55cd70350f3). One of the change is:

> `* semantics.c (finish_id_expression): Replace use of thread_local`
>   `variable with a call to its wrapper.`

So the run-time penalty is that, every reference of the `thread_local` variable will become a function call. Let's check with a simple test case:

```
// 3.cpp
extern thread_local int tls;    
int main() {
    tls += 37;   // line 6
    tls &= 11;   // line 7
    tls ^= 3;    // line 8
    return 0;
}

// 4.cpp

thread_local int tls = 42;
```

When compiled*, we see that *every* use of the `tls` reference becomes a function call to `_ZTW3tls`, which lazily initialize the the variable once:

```
00000000004005b0 <main>:
main():
  4005b0:   55                          push   rbp
  4005b1:   48 89 e5                    mov    rbp,rsp
  4005b4:   e8 26 00 00 00              call   4005df <_ZTW3tls>    // line 6
  4005b9:   8b 10                       mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rax]
  4005bb:   83 c2 25                    add    edx,0x25
  4005be:   89 10                       mov    DWORD PTR [rax],edx
  4005c0:   e8 1a 00 00 00              call   4005df <_ZTW3tls>    // line 7
  4005c5:   8b 10                       mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rax]
  4005c7:   83 e2 0b                    and    edx,0xb
  4005ca:   89 10                       mov    DWORD PTR [rax],edx
  4005cc:   e8 0e 00 00 00              call   4005df <_ZTW3tls>    // line 8
  4005d1:   8b 10                       mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rax]
  4005d3:   83 f2 03                    xor    edx,0x3
  4005d6:   89 10                       mov    DWORD PTR [rax],edx
  4005d8:   b8 00 00 00 00              mov    eax,0x0              // line 9
  4005dd:   5d                          pop    rbp
  4005de:   c3                          ret

00000000004005df <_ZTW3tls>:
_ZTW3tls():
  4005df:   55                          push   rbp
  4005e0:   48 89 e5                    mov    rbp,rsp
  4005e3:   b8 00 00 00 00              mov    eax,0x0
  4005e8:   48 85 c0                    test   rax,rax
  4005eb:   74 05                       je     4005f2 <_ZTW3tls+0x13>
  4005ed:   e8 0e fa bf ff              call   0 <tls> // initialize the TLS
  4005f2:   64 48 8b 14 25 00 00 00 00  mov    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x0
  4005fb:   48 c7 c0 fc ff ff ff        mov    rax,0xfffffffffffffffc
  400602:   48 01 d0                    add    rax,rdx
  400605:   5d                          pop    rbp
  400606:   c3                          ret
```

Compare it with the `__thread` version, which won't have this extra wrapper:

```
00000000004005b0 <main>:
main():
  4005b0:   55                          push   rbp
  4005b1:   48 89 e5                    mov    rbp,rsp
  4005b4:   48 c7 c0 fc ff ff ff        mov    rax,0xfffffffffffffffc // line 6
  4005bb:   64 8b 00                    mov    eax,DWORD PTR fs:[rax]
  4005be:   8d 50 25                    lea    edx,[rax+0x25]
  4005c1:   48 c7 c0 fc ff ff ff        mov    rax,0xfffffffffffffffc
  4005c8:   64 89 10                    mov    DWORD PTR fs:[rax],edx
  4005cb:   48 c7 c0 fc ff ff ff        mov    rax,0xfffffffffffffffc // line 7
  4005d2:   64 8b 00                    mov    eax,DWORD PTR fs:[rax]
  4005d5:   89 c2                       mov    edx,eax
  4005d7:   83 e2 0b                    and    edx,0xb
  4005da:   48 c7 c0 fc ff ff ff        mov    rax,0xfffffffffffffffc
  4005e1:   64 89 10                    mov    DWORD PTR fs:[rax],edx
  4005e4:   48 c7 c0 fc ff ff ff        mov    rax,0xfffffffffffffffc // line 8
  4005eb:   64 8b 00                    mov    eax,DWORD PTR fs:[rax]
  4005ee:   89 c2                       mov    edx,eax
  4005f0:   83 f2 03                    xor    edx,0x3
  4005f3:   48 c7 c0 fc ff ff ff        mov    rax,0xfffffffffffffffc
  4005fa:   64 89 10                    mov    DWORD PTR fs:[rax],edx
  4005fd:   b8 00 00 00 00              mov    eax,0x0                // line 9
  400602:   5d                          pop    rbp
  400603:   c3                          ret
```

This wrapper is not needed for in every use case of `thread_local` though. This can be revealed from [`decl2.c`](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blobdiff;f=gcc/cp/decl2.c;h=688a72332cec582910e9f76708f63afd92b2b4db;hp=f7db1d81b5d905b1fd256a434407a87c0db8a8a6;hb=462819c8e20aab1124e95392974dd55cd70350f3;hpb=db019d30742cffe8f8d86560ea33e61b35269321). 
The wrapper is generated only when:

- It is *not* function-local, and,

  1. It is `extern` (the example shown above), or
  2. The type has a non-trivial destructor (which is not allowed for `__thread` variables), or
  3. The type variable is initialized by a non-constant-expression (which is also not allowed for `__thread` variables).

In all other use cases, it behaves the same as `__thread`. That means, unless you have some `extern __thread` variables, you could replace all `__thread` by `thread_local` without any loss of performance.

---

*: I compiled with -O0 because the inliner will make the function boundary less visible. Even if we turn up to -O3 those initialization checks still remain.

Comment: That's remarkably stupid. Sure, it means you don't have to any kind of call-flow analysis to determine if there's a preceding access to `tls`, but even the most naive analysis would have detected that the access on line 7 absolutely cannot be the first access.

Comment: @MSalters, patches welcome if you can improve it! :)  The thread that begins at http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2012-10/msg00024.html has some relevant discussion

Answer (score 15):

C++11 thread_local has the same runtime effect as the __thread specifier (`__thread` is not part of the C standard; `thread_local` is part of the C++ standard)

it depends where the TLS variable (declared with `__thread` specifier) is declared.

- if TLS variable is declared in an executable then access is fast
- if TLS variable is declared within shared library code (compiled with `-fPIC` compiler option) and `-ftls-model=initial-exec` compiler option is specified then access is fast; however the following limitation applies: the shared library can't be loaded via dlopen/dlsym (dynamic loading), the only way of using the library is to link with it during compilation (linker option `-l<libraryname>` )
- if TLS variable is declared within a shared library (`-fPIC` compiler option set) then access is very slow, as the general dynamic TLS model is assumed - here each access to a TLS variable results in a call to `_tls_get_addr()` ; this is the default case because you are not limited in the way that the shared library is used.

Sources: ELF Handling For Thread-Local Storage by Ulrich Drepper 
https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf
this text also lists the code that is generated for the supported target platforms.

Answer (score 11):

If the variable is defined in the current TU, the inliner will take care of the overhead.  I expect that this will be true of most uses of thread_local.

For extern variables, if the programmer can be sure that no use of the variable in a non-defining TU needs to trigger dynamic initialization (either because the variable is statically initialized, or a use of the variable in the defining TU will be executed before any uses in another TU), they can avoid this overhead with the -fno-extern-tls-init option.

Comment: Almost invariably my use of `thread_local` is via a pattern like `T& f() { thread_local t; return t; }`.  I'm using gcc 4.7 so I currently use a "workaround" to implement thread_local that I wrote here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12049684/1131467.  How does the overhead of the 4.8 implementation compare to my 4.7 workaround implementation for the case of the `f` function?

Comment: Here is a direct link to 4.7 workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12053862/1131467

Comment: The release notes entry is talking about non-function-local variables; for a local variable like t in your example, the 4.8 implementation should be similar to or slightly more efficient than your workaround.